# Animate a plane that transforms to a mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers

How could I animate a plane that transforms to a sphere using Blender ?
I know you can transform a cube to a sphere using shape keys, but is this possible for a plane ?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out this technique [from a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXgZ-QAhMuA) that uses another software.
But it applies on Blender:

1. create a plane and subdivise it so it has enough vertexes (eg. 10 times)
2. add an empty at the same place, and set the rotation to *X:90°*
3. add a SimpleDeform modifier on the plane

   1. Switch mode to *Bend*
   2. Set *Axis, Origin* to your empty
   3. Set Deform Angle to *360°* so it becomes a tube
4. duplicate your empty and sets its rotation to *X:90° / Z:90°*
5. add a second SimpleDeform modifier on the plane

   1. Switch mode to *Bend*
   2. Set *Axis, Origin* to your second empty
   3. Set Deform Angle to *360°* so it becomes a sphere !

Et voilà ! You can now animate both deform angle from the SimpleDeform Modifiers to animate it.